# How can I protect small fruit plants that were planted in the fall to survive the winter?

Tags: overwintering

I have two blueberry bushes and some raspberry bushes that are suppose to be delivered next month. I was planning on planting them in the ground, but it doesn't seem like it will be a whole lot of time after for them to get established before winter.

I live in Zone six, and our winter is usually pretty late, it will get cold in december and snow in January.

I was wondering if there was a way I could make sure they're protected over the winter, so that the frost and cold wouldn't be so much of a worry for them. Or maybe it's not a worry at all?

I was thinking about making a little greenhouse type structure with some scrap wood and painter's plastic.

Comment: My dad's had a lot of success with hugelkulturing small fruit trees.  He buries whole stumps and logs all around liittle fruit trees, can offer some frost protection later on.  As for whether they will survive this year, you may not have a problem but a protective structure would work.  Even a hanging tarp upwind provides a surprising amount of protection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience here on the edge of zones 4 and 5, fall is a fine time to plant perennials and small fruits. I've planted as late as early October with no winter protection other than a few inches of mulch and the plants do just fine. You're a zone warmer planting a month earlier, so it seems it will be even less of a worry for you. I'd just mulch them normally.

Answer (score 3):

I think that as long as there is no new growth after planting, before winter, you'll be absolutely fine. I'm in zone six too, and I think fall planting is even better than spring planting, as it allows the plants to establish the root system a little before it has to put out top growth.

The only time I wasn't completely successful was when I planted an almond tree in September. It put out growth right away, which didn't have time to harden off, and was winter killed.

So, seeing that all you've ordered were blueberries and raspberries, it looks like you will be fine. As @michelle says, just add a little mulch.